# How to retrieve and create the Toggle Heading blocks?

Tags: notion-api

I want to create the toggle headings 1-3 via the Notion API. However, I cannot find the distinction between normal headers and toggle headers in the API.

https://developers.notion.com/reference/block#heading-one-blocks — this doc only lists `"type": "heading_1"` without any additional properties to distinguish the toggle header from the normal (non-toggle) header.

When I get the toggle header block via API, I also cannot see any properties that indicate that the header is a toggle heading:
[image: Getting a toggle heading 1 block via Notion API - IntelliJ Debugger]

Is it overall possible to create the toggle headings via the API? If yes then how?

Comment: Probably it's non-directly possible via `has_children` property: Toggle header can have `has_children == true` , while the non-toggle header is always `has_children == false`.

Comment: Trying to create child block in the Heading 1 block created also via Notion API returns an error :( 
`Got an error from Notion (status: 400, code: validation_error, message: Block does not support children.)`

Comment: Adding the paragraph to an existing toggle heading is working, however. So there should be some inexplicit way to create heading as a toggle heading. Still unclear for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the API itself actually supports creating the headings with the `children` in it which will make the header a toggle header.

It's just the wrapping JVM library that I am using that does not support setting children to the HeadingOne, HeadingTwo, HeadingThree blocks.

I've added an issue for the library, see https://github.com/seratch/notion-sdk-jvm/issues/45.

Working example via the pure API (replace `YOUR_PAGE_ID` with your Notion page id) and set the `NOTION_API_TOKEN` to your Notion token:

```sh
curl -X PATCH 'https://api.notion.com/v1/blocks/YOUR_PAGE_ID/children' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer '"$NOTION_API_KEY"'' \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Notion-Version: 2022-02-22" \
  --data '{
  "children": [
    {
      "object": "block",
      "type": "heading_2",
      "heading_2": {
        "rich_text": [{ "type": "text", "text": { "content": "Heading 2 from script (try 3)" } }],
        "children": [
          {
            "object": "block",
            "type": "paragraph",
            "paragraph": {
              "rich_text": [
                {
                  "type": "text",
                  "text": {
                    "content": "Child in heading 2."
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```